# $\cos x = b$ have 2 or 4 solutions?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

In my high school, when we used to have an equation:
$$\cos x =b,$$
we write that $x$ = $\pm \arccos b$. but using the trigonometric circle, we should worry about the sign of $b$. because if $b$ is negative then we are in the 2nd and 3rd quadrant, and being positive means in the first and fourth quadrant. So how then saying this equation does have 2 solutions? plus in this case, if 2nd and 3rd quadrant would be the solution  $x$ = $\pm \arccos b$ any more aplicable?

Comment: $\cos x=b$ has either $0$ or countable infinitely many solutions. With the restriction that $x\in(-\pi,\pi]$ it has $0$ solutions if $\lvert b\rvert>1$, $1$ solution if $\lvert b\rvert=1$ and $2$ solutions if $\lvert b\rvert<1$.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions of the equation are in the intersections of the graph of the cosine with the horizontal line $y=b$. So, if $-1\leq b \leq 1$ the equation has an infinite number of solutions, while for other values of $b$ there is no solution.